# how do I grep specific pattern from a Line using grep command?

Tags: grep

to be more clear, I need to get the used space percentage (only the percentage without the other content in the line<  of VOL (line 7)
**Using grep command***

Comment: If you're obtaining these lines from the `df` command, you may wish to take a look at its `--output` option ex. `df --output=pcent /dev/sda3`

Answer (score 3):

Use grep with lookahead. It looks for one or more number followed by a `%` and only prints the number.

```
grep -Po "[0-9]+(?=%)"
```

- `-P` : Perl-compatible regular expression so we can  use lookahead.
- `-o` : Only print the matched parts.

---

```
$ echo '/dev/sda3 22G 4.1G 17G 20% /vol/store' | grep -Po "[0-9]+(?=%)"
20
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
echo "/dev/sda3        22G  4.1G   17G  20% /vol/store" | grep -o "[[:digit:]]*%"
20%
```

Without the % sign:

```
echo "/dev/sda3        22G  4.1G   17G  20% /vol/store" | grep -Po "[[:digit:]]*(?=%)"
20
```